# How to confirm to matching email fields?

Tags: html

I'm creating a "Event Form" where people should be able to sign-up for comming events. 
I added two fields for email. One for them to write their email in and the second one to confirm the email.

I want them to write it twice to ensure that we are getting the right email. 
When the email in field 2 (Bekräfta Email) is wrong they should get an error message.

But it seems like I'm doing something wrong with the code.

**This is the HTML-Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openTerms(id) {
    var terms = {"1":"Med detta villkor godkännes att Svenska Bostadsfonden Management AB får använda min personliga information så som,namn, telefonnummer, mail, arbetstitel, arbetsplats, postadress och besöksadress i syfte att...... I enlighet med GDPR och lagen och samtycke.......","2":"Terms of conditions bla bla bla","3":null,"4":null,"5":null,"6":null,"7":null};
    var preview = window.open("", "", "height=700,width=800,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no,menu=no,titlebar=no,location=no,addressbar=no");
    var html="<head><meta charset=\"UTF-8\"><style>body {margin: 0; padding: 20px;color: #333;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 14px;}</style></head><body>" + terms[id] + "</body>";
    preview.document.write(html);
    }
</script>
<form id="up-form" name="form_8311ud1507fd3ad2e43278424bca0e4adc3bd" action="https://power.upsales.com/api/external/formSubmit" method="POST">
    <div>
        <label>Jag vill beställa</label>
        <br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="Aktuellt faktablad" name="Extra.1547544176421">&nbsp;Aktuellt faktablad&nbsp;</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="Aktuell broschyr" name="Extra.1547544176421">&nbsp;Aktuell broschyr&nbsp;</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Jag vill beställa i egenskap av</label>
        <br>
        <select name="Extra.1547544378077">
<option></option>
<option value="Befintlig kund">Befintlig kund</option>
<option value="Intresserad investerare">Intresserad investerare</option>
<option value="Finansiell rådgivare">Finansiell rådgivare</option>
<option value="Media/analytiker">Media/analytiker</option>
<option value="Annat">Annat</option>
</select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Namn *</label>
        <br>
        <input maxlength="512" type="text" name="Contact.name" required="required">
    </div>
    <div class="email">
        <label>Email *</label>
        <br>
        <input maxlength="512" type="email" id="up-email-input" autocomplete="off" name="Contact.email" required="required">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Bekräfta Email *</label>
        <br>
        <input maxlength="512" type="text" name="Extra.1547643200666" required="required">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Telefon *</label>
        <br>
        <input maxlength="512" type="text" id="up-client-name-input" name="Client.name" required="required">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Postadress *</label>
        <br>
        <input maxlength="512" type="text" name="Extra.1547544152076" required="required">
    </div>
    <!-- REQUIRED FIELDS -->
    <input type="hidden" name="formCid" value="8311">
    <input type="hidden" name="formId" value="8311ud1507fd3ad2e43278424bca0e4adc3bd">
    <input type="hidden" name="isFrame" value="false">
    <input type="text" value="" name="validation" style="display: none;">
    <!-- END OF REQUIRED FIELDS -->
    <button type="submit">Skicka</button>
</form>
<script src="https://img.upsales.com/2XybO6NW9Y+uyQU9cm4CLw==/be.js"></script>
```

**I added the following to the code:**

```
              <div class="email">
                                                          <label>Email *</label>
                                                          <br>
                                                          <input maxlength="512" type="email" id="up-email-input" autocomplete="off" name="Contact.email" required="required">
                             </div>
                             <div>
                                                          <label>Bekräfta Email *</label>
                                                          <br>
                                                          <input maxlength="512" type="text" name="Extra.1547643200666" required="required">
                             </div>
if (trim($fv->txt_Bekräfta Email) != $fv->txt_Email) {
        $e->defineError("invalid_email", "Your Email address do not match", "txt_Bekräfta Email");

Seems like the following sequence does not work:

if (trim($fv->txt_Bekräfta Email) != $fv->txt_Email) {
        $e->defineError("invalid_email", "Your Email address do not match", "txt_Bekräfta Email");
```

Comment: You are trimming the `txt_Bekräfta Email` but not the `txt_mail` and you should give both inputs a different ID

Comment: Because of that, your emails could not be the same, maybe you should show us some more PHP code

Comment: Thats all code I have @JelleBotman

Comment: No there should be more PHP code?